# How to add content_panels when I edit Page

Tags: django, wagtail

I am developing my wagtail blog site.
I want to add the feature what SnippetChooserPanel is shown dynamicaly.
When I create a Blog editing page, I want to edit 1/3 SnippetChooserPanel.
When I edit a Blog editing page, I want to edit 3/3 SnippetChooserPanel.

However, I could not resolve it...

1. I removed 2 SnippetChooserPanel,"B" and "C" in blog/models.py. I can edit only "A" SnippetChooserPanel -> it is OK.
2. I added code in blog/wagtail_hooks.py -> However, SnippetChooserPanel could not see.

It is blog/models.py

```
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                SnippetChooserPanel("A"),
                # SnippetChooserPanel("B"),
                # SnippetChooserPanel("C"),
            ],
            heading=_("ABC information"),
        ),
    ]
```

It is process of 2 and blog/wagtail_hooks.py. If I added

```
@hooks.register("before_edit_page")

...
...

Page.content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                SnippetChooserPanel("B"),
                SnippetChooserPanel("C"),
            ],
            heading=_("ABC more information"),
        ),
    ]

...
...
```

I can not do it well..
Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and found a solution, although that might not be the ideal one.

In `wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py`, I read:

```py
class ModelAdmin(WagtailRegisterable):

    def get_edit_handler(self, instance, request):
        """
        Returns the appropriate edit_handler for this modeladmin class.
        edit_handlers can be defined either on the model itself or on the
        modeladmin (as property edit_handler or panels). Falls back to
        extracting panel / edit handler definitions from the model class.
        """
        if hasattr(self, 'edit_handler'):
            edit_handler = self.edit_handler
        elif hasattr(self, 'panels'):
            panels = self.panels
            edit_handler = ObjectList(panels)
        …
        return edit_handler
```

Therefore, you could override that `get_edit_handler` to decide what you want to return. If this is a create view, the instance will be null, otherwise, it will have an id.

```py
# wagtail_hooks.py
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import ObjectList

class BlogAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Blog

    def get_edit_handler(self, instance, request):
        panels = instance.create_panels
        if instance.pk:
            panels += instance.edit_panels
        return ObjectList(panels)


# models.py

class Blog(Page):

    create_panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("A"),
    ]
    edit_panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("B"),
        SnippetChooserPanel("C"),
    ]
```

That's it.